# Getting error in Axois in catch and after dispatch value didn't getting in props

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, lumen

I'm new in Redux React and creating web app where app interact with Lumen API framework. When a request go to server and return with error code 400, 404, 500 any status code (error) except 200 it shows console error and processed after that in React.

I tried pass value when get error at `axois.catch({dispatch})` but value update in state by viewing redux-dev-tool but didn't get value at props.

As from API I passed as like:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json(['type'=> 'error','message'=> $validator->errors()->all()],400);
}
```

And in my action file as like:

```
export const loginRequest = formValues => async dispatch => {

await user.post('/user/create', { ...formValues, device_id: 12345}).then(response => {
  dispatch ({type: LOGIN, payload: response.data});
}).catch(error => {
  if(error.response) {
    dispatch ({ type: ERRORS, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
});
}
```

and in reducer:

```
const INTIAL_STATE = {
    isSignedIn: null,
    accessToken: null,
    loginMessage: null,
    errorMessage: null
};

export default (state = INTIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case ERRORS:
        return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, accessToken:null , errorMessage: action.payload };
    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

as last in my component file:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {error: state.auth.errorMessage};
};
```

and console log in render method:

```
console.log(this.props);
```

I'm getting `POST http://localhost:8000/user/create 500 (Internal Server Error)` in my console but the errorMessage value updated in state as looked in redux-dev-tool and after error no code run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **redux-saga-routines** for dispatching actions, make your work easy with this module. 
Here its documentation link https://github.com/afitiskin/redux-saga-routines